# Faking a FTP service

Tags: ftp, nmap

I am writing a piece of software which can fool Nmap into believing that GuildFTPd FTP Server is running on port 21. My python code so far looks like this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket( )
s.bind(('', 21))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
conn.send("220-GuildFTPd FTP Server (c) 1997-2002\r\n220-Version 0.999.14")
conn.close()
```

The Nmap regexp for matching this particular service is:

```
match ftp m|^220-GuildFTPd FTP Server \(c\) \d\d\d\d(-\d\d\d\d)?\r\n220-Version (\d[-.\w]+)\r\n| p/Guild ftpd/ v/$2/ o/Windows/
```

However when I scan the host which is running the script with Nmap the results are:

```
21/tcp open ftp?
```

How can this be? When I scan the real service with Nmap it identifies the service correctly.

Comment: My guess would be that there's more to the ftp protocol. You give nmap a response, which lets it know there is *a program* at that port. But, it doesn't know if it is actually an ftp server, since the command set isn't correct.

Comment: I sniffed the real application with Wireshark and it doesn't seem to send any extra info so I am still puzzled..

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing a `\r\n` at the end of your fake response that the match line needs.

The other major issue is that your program only handles one connection, then closes. Nmap will first do a port scan, then send service fingerprinting probes. If you ran nmap as root (or Administrator on Windows), it would use a half-open TCP SYN scan, and your application wouldn't see the portscan as a connection, but otherwise it will accept the portscan, close the connection, and be unavailable for the service scan phase.

Here's a very basic adaptation of your script that can handle sequential connections (but not parallel), which is enough to fool Nmap:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket( )
s.bind(('', 21))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.send("220-GuildFTPd FTP Server (c) 1997-2002\r\n220-Version 0.999.14\r\n")
    conn.close()
```